# proof by mathematical induction divide a convex polygon of n sides into triangles

Tags: induction

The question is "Determine the number of diagonals (that do not intersect) necessary to divide a convex polygon of n sides into triangles."

I am having problems approaching this question can any one give me some ideas of how approaching these types of question any help will be appreciated

Comment: The question is not very clear. Determine the number of _what_?

Comment: What is it you are proving by induction?

Comment: sorry about that, the question was asking about the number of diagonals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** A little experimentation leads to the conjecture we can do it using $n-3$ diagonals.

For the induction step, suppose this is true for a convex polygon with $k$ sides. To deal with the case $k+1$, let $P,Q,R$ be consecutive vertices, and join $PR$. That divides our polygon into a triangle and a convex polygon with $k$ sides. Apply the induction hypothesis to this polygon.

**Added:** The phrasing "are needed" suggests that we also should prove that we cannot do it with *fewer* than $n-3$ lines. For that, *strong induction* is the right tool.

In the case $n=3$, we certainly need at least $n-3$ diagonals. Suppose that at least $n-3$ diagonals are needed for all convex $k$-gons with $k\lt n$. We show at least $n-3$ diagonals are needed for a convex $n$-gon.

So take a a division of the polygon into triangles by non-intersecting diagonals. Let $\ell$ be one of the diagonals of this division. This divides our $n$-gon into a $p$-gon and a $q$-gon, where $p+q=n+2$. By the induction hypothesis, at least $p-3$ diagonals are needed for the $p$-gon, and at least $q-3$ for the $q$-gon. This gives (including $\ell$) a total of at least $(p-3)+(q-3)+1=(p+q)-5=(n+2)-5=n-3$ diagonals.

Answer (score 1):

The proof by induction would start with the base case, a triangle, for which the answer is 0, as it is a triangle itself. So for n=3, diagonals=0.
Now take a four-sided poligon and from one of its vertex, say A, draw a diagonal. By doing this we get 2 triangles, so the answer for n=4 is d=1. 
Now add one side to the polygon, a new vertex will be added as well, and we can match our vertex A with this new vertex obtaining a new triangle. So the answer for n=4+1 is d=1+1
By induction, for n=k, d=(k-4)+= k-3

So the answer is n-3